# Как правильно сделать 301 редирект в .htaccess?

Tags: редирект, apache, .htaccess

Добрый день, всем участникам Тостера.

Как сделать правильный 301ый редирект с http://www.site.ru/index.php, http://site.ru/index.php, http://site.ru/ на http://www.site.ru/?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот подробная инфа [301 редирект](http://phpworking.ru/php/301-redirekt-%E2%80%93-gramotnaya-pereadresaciya-htaccess-i-php-header/)